# web_reg_find function return error 26366

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I run a script:

```
web_url("yangibazar@ya.ru",
"URL=http://u0351361.isp.regruhosting.ru/viewtopic.php?t=11", 
"TargetFrame=", 
"Resource=0", 
"RecContentType=text/html",
"Referer=http://u0351361.isp.regruhosting.ru/viewforum.php?f=3", 
"Snapshot=t6.inf", 
"Mode=HTML", 
LAST);

lr_think_time(20);

web_reg_find("Text=templates/subSilver/images/icon_mini_faq.gif",LAST );

web_reg_find("Text=u=16",LAST );
```

---

First web_reg_find finds string, second - returns Error

```
 118    Action.c(118): Error -26366: "Text=u=16" not found for web_reg_find   [MsgId: MERR-26366]   Action.c
```

But snapshot t6.inf response from previous  web_url("yangibazar@ya.ru"...  contains both strings. Actualy the the problem is that some stings can be found in response, some not. 
view-source:http://u0351361.isp.regruhosting.ru/viewtopic.php?t=11 - code of that page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context for a service function is that it is initiated prior to the call where you are interested in finding the result.  In this sense the service function (web_reg_*) acts like a sieve through which all of the responding HTML is poured.  The conditions on the web_reg_* function determine what (if anything) is caught in the sieve at the end for evaluation.

In the code example provided above the service functions are called after the web_url().  Their context for operation would be the following request, not the previous one.  The issue here is conceptual which impacts your implementation.

This concept is covered extensively as part of the product training.  If your management refuses to send you to training and provide a mentor for a period of time (a minimum when moving to a new discipline/tool) then you should consider downloading the self paced tutorial from the HP website.